# Python: How to output block of C structs above loop using Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, c, templates, jinja2

I am not even quite sure if this is possible.  Basically, I have a Jinja2 template with a for loop.  I want to know is there a want to output code outside of the loop if certain conditions are met.  I will try to use Jinja2 code and some pseudocode as an example:

```
display_above()
this text will not be in the for loop

{%- for foo in bar -%}
    this text is below
    {% if condition == met %}
        {# the condition is met #}
        call display_above() or some function
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I attempted to use a macro, but the text was wrapped inside the for loop.  The reason why I want to do this is because the Jinja2 template is creating a C file.  In this C file, there is a struct of structs.  The main_struct is defined using the for loop, but I want to define the sub_structs that are within the main_struct above the main_struct.

Just to note: I do have a working solution that uses two separate loops, one to define the main_struct and one to define the sub_structs.  I am trying to compact this down to using a single loop, so if there is another way other than loops, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You should ask on the mailing list though: http://jinja.pocoo.org/community/#mailinglist